# ghostscript distroy gradient eps file in outline mode

Tags: gradient, ghostscript, eps

I have two EPS files.

One is with gradient and other is without.

When I convert my EPS file (NOTE: without gradient) to PDF using ghostscript. If looks correct in outline mode.

But when I convert EPS file with gradient via ghostscript, it black out my image.

here is my command,

> -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dEPSFitPage -sOutputFile=output.eps -sDEVICE=ps2write -c '<< /PageSize [500 500] >> setpagedevice' -f" . myeps.eps

Answer (score 0):

What version of Ghostscript, which OS ? Where can we download a specimen file to investigate ?

Command line is useless without specimen file.

Comment: I use GS 9.05 with Ubuntu 12.04. 

And here is the eps http://social.gunjan.intern.redweb.dk/myeps.eps

Comment: Seems like you've hit a bug with EPSFitPage, if the media is square it looks like it doesn't know which scale to use, and so you get nothing (possibly a scale factor of 0 I haven't checked). I'd suggest you open a bug report. Oh and the current version of GS is 9.10, 9.11 will be released in a couple of months. By the way, given that the original of this EPS was a PDF file, this seems like an exercise (PDF->EPS->PDF) likely to cause problems.

Comment: probably I passed you processed EPS. I have replaced new one, and I have tried to upgrade my version but it says, I have latest version. so I would assume, 9.10 is not for ubuntu.

Comment: and other eps file works with epsfit only gradient eps does not work.

Comment: Just because there isn't a Ubuntu package doesn't mean that you can't use GS, its open source after all. However I happen to know that the maintainer for Ubuntu keeps bang up to date with Ghostscript, so you should definitely be able to get 9.10. My comment regarding reporting a bug stands however, it doesn't matter whether the EPS has been 'processed' or not. Try changing your page size to [500 501] and you'll see the result.

Comment: and it seems while copy a command I missed square parenthesis. I have edited my command, can you please try now?

Comment: I already fixed the problem with the missing mark '[' and tried it that way before my comment.

Comment: oppss, okay, I have added bug on ghostscript, lets see what they have to say about it, Thanks alot  kens.

Comment: Hey kens, I posted bug here https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ghostscript/+bug/1274888
 
But did have reply yet, do you have any other place where can we get fast reply, or can you post my question at right place

Comment: Don't report it to Ubuntu, report it to Ghostscript.